# Odoo add field in res.partner and show in account_aged_partner_balance

Tags: odoo-14

I tried to make new field in res.partner and to show in aged_payble inside accounting module but getting error partner_code_seq field doesn't exist

```
_inherit = "account.aged.payable"

partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner')
partner_code_seq = fields.Char(group_operator='max')

@api.model
def _get_column_details(self, options):
    print("Hello")
    res = super(ReportAccountAgedPayable, self)._get_column_details(options)
    res += [
        self._field_column('partner_code_seq')
    ]
    return res
```

Comment: Update from terminal or watch odoo mate video of how to update partner field

Comment: Hey, can you locate the file where account.aged.payable model exists? I am having issue on editing the account->report->aged payable report. I want to show the multi-currency in the report. However, I didn't find anything.